# How to get size of hidden files with "du"

Tags: bash, shell

I've been using "du -hs ~/" to get the size of my total home directory with outputs 20GB, and I've been trying to where large files that I can delete to free up some space. However, when using "du -hs ~/*" I get numerous outputted files *but* they don't sum to 20GB. There are a few hidden files but they aren't shown.

How can I print out the size of hidden files, and also locate the largest files/directories via command line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies not with `du` but with how the shell resolves `*` - it does not include files that start with a period. To remedy, just mention those files explicitly:

```
du -hs ~/* ~/.*
```

In order to find the largest of those files, simply pipe the output to a `sort` command, with an optional `tail` appended:

```
du -hs ~/* ~/.* | sort -h | tail
```

Comment: Just want to add that this solution also leads to `~/..` being included, in my case resulting in a huge number of "access denied" warnings for the homes of other users.

A workaround I came up with is this: `for f in $(ls -a ~); do if [[ "$f" != ".." ]]; then du -hs $f; fi; done`

Answer (score 3):

To size all the files in home directories including hidden files

```bash
du -sh $(ls -A)
```

```bash
du -sh .[^.]* *
```

To size only normal files

```bash
du -sh *
```

To size only hidden files

```bash
du -sh .[^.]*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

Running this command will display the disk usage summary (du -hs) for each hidden directory found.

Comment: adding `-mindepth 1` to filter out the `~/` folder

Answer (score 0):

For me, has to filter out ".":

```
ls . |grep -v "\.$"
```